# Pony ORM PermissionError in access rule for to_json function

Tags: python, pony, ponyorm

I have a problem trying to grasp and to understand why its happen.
i'm using Pony ORM, https://ponyorm.com, for models the problem i'm trying to solve.

I'm trying to send the query result in json format using to_json function from database instance.

Here the code i'm used.

```
from pony.orm import *
db = Database()

#entities definition

class User(db.Entity):
    nama = Required(str)
    admin = Required(bool, default=False)
    diklat = Optional('Diklat')


class Diklat(db.Entity):
    nama = Required(str)
    finished = Required(bool, default=False)
    peserta = Set(User)

# database binding
db.bind('sqlite', ':memory:', create_db=True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

# test data
with db_session:
    u1 = User(nama='user 1')
    u2 = User(nama='user 2', admin=True)
    u3 = User(nama='user 3')
    d1 = Diklat(nama='diklat 1')
    d2 = Diklat(nama='diklat 2', finished=True)
    # add user to diklat
    d1.peserta.add(u1)
    d1.peserta.add(u2)
    d2.peserta.add(u3)
    flush()
    commit()

# access rules setup

@user_groups_getter(User)
def user_groups(user):
    if user.admin:
        return ['admin', 'user']
    return ['user']

@user_roles_getter(User, Diklat)
def user_roles(user, diklat):
    if user in diklat.peserta:
        return ['peserta']
    return ['nonpeserta']

@obj_labels_getter(Diklat)
def obj_labels(diklat):
    if diklat.finished:
        return ['finished']
    return ['process']


# permission setup
with db.set_perms_for(Diklat):
    perm('view', role='peserta')

# some function to get data in form of json 
def get_diklat():
    d = select(d for d in Diklat)
    return db.to_json(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with db_session:
        user1 = User[1]
        user2 = User[2]
        user3 = User[3]
        diklat = Diklat[1]
        set_current_user(user1)
        print("current user should 'User[1]':", get_current_user())
        print("User group user should '['user']':", user_groups(user1))
        print("User group user2 should '['admin', 'user']':", user_groups(user2))
        print("User group user3 should '['user']':", user_groups(user3))
        print("Roles for user and diklat should '['peserta']' :", user_roles(user1, diklat))
        print("Roles for user2 and diklat should '['peserta']' :", user_roles(user2, diklat))
        print("Roles for user3 and diklat should '['nonpeserta']' :", user_roles(user3, diklat))
        print("Object labels for diklat, should '['process']':", obj_labels(diklat))
        print(get_diklat())
```

And the problems is permission setup for get_diklat() getting to access the role ...here the result traceback

```
>>>
current user should 'User[1]': User[1]
User group user should '['user']': ['user']
User group user2 should '['admin', 'user']': ['admin', 'user']
User group user3 should '['user']': ['user']
Roles for user and diklat should '['peserta']' : ['peserta']
Roles for user2 and diklat should '['peserta']' : ['peserta']
Roles for user3 and diklat should '['nonpeserta']' : ['nonpeserta']
Object labels for diklat, should '['process']': ['process']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/******/test.py", line 82, in <module>
    get_diklat()
  File "C:/Users/******/test.py", line 64, in get_diklat
    return db.to_json(d)
  File "<string>", line 2, in to_json
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\site-packages\pony\utils\utils.py", line 58, in cut_traceback
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 1020, in to_json
    data_json = json.dumps(data, default=obj_converter)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 1014, in obj_converter
    user_has_no_rights_to_see(obj)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 1004, in user_has_no_rights_to_see
    % (user, sorted(user_groups), obj))
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\env35\lib\site-packages\pony\utils\utils.py", line 96, in throw
    raise exc
pony.orm.core.PermissionError: The current user User[1] which belongs to groups ['anybody', 'user'] has no rights to see the object Diklat[2] on the frontend
>>>
```

Based on above permission setup, and miss a bit docs, https://docs.ponyorm.com/ponyjs_security.html?highlight=permissions_for, i think the roles for the current user was setup with the right thing,

```
 # permission setup
    with db.set_perms_for(Diklat):
        perm('view', role='peserta')
```

role of the current user, (see example data)...i think its right
so, what the problems was ?? why pony says :

```
pony.orm.core.PermissionError: The current user User[1] which belongs to groups ['anybody', 'user'] has no rights to see the object Diklat[2] on the frontend
```

...
I cant understand why this happen ??
thanks for the help
best regards...

[updated]
If i change the permission setup like this,

```
# permission setup
with db.set_perms_for(Diklat):
    perm('view', group='user')
```

its worked like i hope..this output from get_diklat() function:

```
{"data": [{"class": "Diklat", "pk": 1}, {"class": "Diklat", "pk": 2}], "objects": {"Diklat": {"1": {"nama": "diklat 1", "id": 1, "finished": false}, "2": {"nama": "diklat 2", "id": 2, "finished": true}}}, "schema": [{"name": "Diklat", "newAttrs": [{"auto": true, "kind": "PrimaryKey", "name": "id", "type": "int"}, {"kind": "Required", "name": "nama", "type": "str"}, {"kind": "Required", "name": "finished", "type": "bool"}], "pkAttrs": ["id"]}], "schema_hash": "600696882295084e228d496c580a1f77"}
```

[Updated]

If i check in interactive console, i think its have permit to view the diklat object

```
>>> diklat
Diklat[1]
>>> user1
User[1]
>>> user2
User[2]
>>> with db_session:
    has_perm(user2, 'view', diklat)


True
>>>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exception arises because the current user does not have `'view'` permission for a specific instance of `Diklat` entity, namely, `Diklat[2]`. This information is specified in the error message: "The current user `User[1]` which belongs to groups `['anybody', 'user']` has no rights to see the object `Diklat[2]` on the frontend".

The permission rules defined as:

```py
with db.set_perms_for(Diklat):
    perm('view', role='peserta')
```

That means that in order to have the `view` permission a user need to have a role `'peserta'` to specific instance of `Diklat`.

According to `user_roles_getter` hook, in order to have a `'peserta'` role a user need to be an item of `diklat.peserta` collection:

```py
@user_roles_getter(User, Diklat)
def user_roles(user, diklat):
    if user in diklat.peserta:
        return ['peserta']
    return ['nonpeserta']
```

The current user `User[1]` does not belong to `Diklat[2].peserta` collection, hence for `Diklat[2]` object it does not have `peserta` role. Because of this, `User[1]` does not have permission `view` for `Diklat[2]` object, and so `Diklat[2]` object cannot be serialized to JSON when the current user is `User[1]`.